# How to output two different audio to two audio devices separately from same Unity3d application

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, fmod

I am developing a two player game in which one player will have to hear one type of audio and second player to hear different audio. The computer is planned to be connected with two audio devices - one headset and another headset using usb sound card. The game is planned to be developed using Unity3d. How to split audio? Is it possible to use FMOD and generate this? How to send separate audio from same game to separate audio devices ? Thanks!

Comment: This may help get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868966/play-a-sound-in-a-specific-device-with-c-sharp

Comment: As far as I know, there's nothing in Unity that directly supports that. You may be able to try various homebrew solutions, but those tend to be brittle across multiple platforms.